# Got SIGABRT when running my first iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

Trying to write my first iPhone application using Xcode 5.1. Here is part of my *AppDelegate* code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddViewController"];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I have a storyboard called "*Main.Storyboard*" with *Navigation Controller* and *View Controller*.

When I run my app I get `SIGABRT error with NSInternalInconsistencyException exception`.

Could anyone help me to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: You should show the entire error message. Normally, after the `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, there is an explanation.

Comment: Maybe an unconnected IBOutlet?

Comment: Thanks to all! There was a broken storyboard file. I recreated it and application started without problem.

Answer (score 2):

why you adding subview as a `UINavigationController.view` and root-view as a `view-controller`?  Your code must be look like this:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddViewController"];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And verified that identifier of your viewcontroller is setting correct or not that you are given in above.

Comment: Just to add something to this answer, make sure you have a viewcontroller with the identifier "AddViewController" in your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UIStoryboard *storyBord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle  mainBundle]];
  self.window.rootViewController = [storyBord instantiateInitialViewController] ;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard as a main interface you don't need to setup any code. So you can add UINavigationController to the scene in you storyboard. Then set rootViewController using connection inspector.

Check the video for understanding: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duvjKZgONlg&feature=youtu.be)

the code will look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```